# Codeigniter - how to combine multiple installations into one

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, installation, subdirectory

When I started my app a few years ago, there where just 2 clients and thus 2 subsites on my domain where I installed the codigniter-built app :

- main domain
- subsites based on client code # : e.g. main/1448 and main/4457
- each subsite containes the same codeingiter app and is run from within the subsite itself ( e.g. main/1448/index.php and main/4457/index.php )
- seperate mysql-databases based on client code #

Over the years my app evolved and I got more users and thus more subsites ( atm about 40 subsites ). This is labor-intensive when creating a new subsite and especially when releasing an update since I have to update all 40 subsites manually.

Is there a way to install the codeigniter installation in my main folder and maintain the url for each subsite ? This will have the consequense that in the url the first item isn't the controller but the subsite follewed by the controller and if needed the method etc. Is this possible ?

Second, is there an easy way to use the subsite-code in the url to define which database the app has to use ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you can use few applications setting:

```
$application_folder = '/path/to/your/application';
```

More information:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html

I have a similar issue, but I've decided to keep all the application separately. I am also thinking how to manage all the apps.
I think one of idea could be to make a script which can check if zip file with an upgrade is available on main site. If yes, download and unzip.
SQL migration is more complicated for me, but CI comes with:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/migration.html